# If each pointwise sequence of derivatives hits a fixed value, is the function a polynomial?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be infinitely differentiable. Suppose there exists an absolute constant $C \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists an $N_x$ such that $f^{(N_x)}(x) = C$. Here $f^{(\ell)}( \cdot )$ denotes the $\ell$-th derivative. Must it be the case that $f$ is a polynomial?

This is a generalization of [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34059/if-f-is-infinitely-differentiable-then-f-coincides-with-a-polynomial) problem, which is the special case with $C=0$. I have attempted to try to reproduce the proofs given on that post (with $0$ replaced with generic $C$), but it seems to me that the arguments there strongly use that $C=0$.

Here is a further generalization. Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be infinitely differentiable. Suppose there exists a real sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $\{a_1, a_2, \cdots\} \cap \{f^{(1)}(x), f^{(2)}(x), \cdots\} \neq \varnothing$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Must $f$ be a polynomial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these generalizations can be solved by essentially the same method as Andrey Gogolev's answer to the question you linked.  As in that answer, let $X$ be the set of points $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is not equal to a polynomial on any neighborhood of $x$.  By the Baire category theorem, you then get an interval $(a,b)$ such that $(a,b)\cap X$ is nonempty and $f^{(n)}$ is constant on $(a,b)\cap X$ for some fixed $n$.  But now since no point of $X$ is isolated, this implies $f^{(n+1)}$ is identically $0$ on $(a,b)\cap X$ (compute the difference quotient using only points of $(a,b)\cap X$).  Iterating this then gives $f^{(m)}=0$ on $(a,b)\cap X$ for all $m\geq n+1$.  The rest of the argument is then the same as in Andrey Gogolev's answer (with $n$ replaced by $n+1$): you conclude that in fact $f^{(n+1)}=0$ on all of $(a,b)$ and so $f$ is a polynomial on $(a,b)$, contradicting the fact that $(a,b)\cap X$ is nonempty.